# Trouble manipulating calculus equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

my maths education is fairly patchy, something I am trying to fix, I'm looking at an example caluclus question and I can't figure out how they get from one step to the next. I general im fine at answering most of the questions I'm doing, sometimes I just get stuck on what kind of manipulation is going on to get the equation from one step to the next.

the step I'm having trouble with is the jump from this:
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty } \left \{ \frac{81}{n^4} \left [ \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \right ]^2 -  \frac{54}{n^2}\frac{n(n+1)}{2} \right \}
$$

to this:

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty } \left [ \frac{81}{4} \left ( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right )^2 - 27\left ( 1+\frac{1}{n} \right )\right ]
$$

I realise that this probably something very simple that I'm missing, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suppose that $x$ is $n$

Comment: yes you're right, my mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can consider the two terms on the left and right of the subtraction independently.
$$
{n(n+1)\over n^2}={n+1 \over n}=1+{1\over n}
$$
plus arithmetic with the numbers gets you the answer for both pieces. For the left hand side you need to use the above twice.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer!

Im still a alittle confused though, where did the n^2 on the bottom come from>

Comment: @Robert - it comes from the $81/n^4$ or the $54/n^2$ terms.

Comment: oh ok, sorry, thats the part i dont get, can you explain how you combine the 81/n^4 with the other term?

Comment: @Robert - ${a\over b}\times{c\over d}={a\over d}\times{c\over b}$.

Comment: ahh i see, and so, when you take the 2 out of the brackets you have to square it and get four, do you square root n^4 before putting it inside the brackets as well, or do you just put it in as is? (sorry for asking so many questions, but THANK YOU!!)

Comment: @Robert - you're welcome. $a^2 b^2 = (ab)^2$ so ${1\over n^4}(c)^2=\left({c\over n^2}\right)^2$.